# wordpress logn - An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server

Tags: php, wordpress, server, ip, mod-security

I cannot access any of my wordpress sites' admin panel. They are showing -

"Not Acceptable!

An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security."

As it is happening for every site it is surely not a server issue. However, when i hide my IP using tool like tunnel bear I can access the admin panel. So i guess the issue is with my IP. But I don't understand what is wrong with my IP.